# Variable to control bezier points in a line for graph in PaintCode

Tags: paintcode

I have just started to use PaintCode some days ago and did all the tutorials but I am banging my head against a very simple task.
I have created a temperature plot with a Bezier and I want to assign a variable to each day so that the point coordinates will be proportional to the temperature.
What is the best way to achieve this? I cannot control the individual Bezier points so I can only move all the curve which is not what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can attach variable to single bezier points. Double-click the bezier to enter editing mode, then select some point and then you can attach variables to the text fields for its X and Y coordinates.

[image: How to]